# What makes Earth-Mars transfers more non-Hohmann; inclination or eccentricity?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mars, mission-design, hohmann-transfer

Answers to [Why do many Mars missions launch now, if the Hohmann transfer orbit is the most propellant-saving one?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/37138/7982) and discussions below them made me wonder what makes Earth-Mars transfers more non-Hohmann; inclination or eccentricity?

So I've asked.

The answer might be different between Earth-to-Mars and Mars-to-Earth, *then again, it might not!*

Maybe it depends on the year? If so, I think which is more often the reason or "on average" might be good enough, but someone may be able to dig up a table somewhere, I can't be the first person to wonder this, and it can be addressed quantitatively with a fairly simple analysis provided a definition for "non-Hohmannness" can be established.

Comment: What’s the metric for non-Hohmannism?

Comment: @RussellBorogove MNU's (Mars Non-[hominy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hominy) Units) is my preference, but I think there's some inclination to allow for more eccentric mectrics.

Comment: Every-Hohmann-Transfer is eccentric? So what do you mean with: eccentricity reduces the value of MNUs?

Comment: @CallMeTom to my understanding formal Hohmann transfers are between *circular orbits* that lie in the same plane. If either orbit has a non-zero eccentricity and/or the planes are not coincident, then MNUs deviate from zero.

Comment: Ahh, okey, I understand....

Comment: So you can basically say: MNU ~ (required_delta_V - ideal_Hohmann_delta_V) ... so lets say "MNU = C * (dV_r - dV_h)". "C" is a constant, so lets just assume "1" (so we sill can keep SI-Units and do not use this silly measurements like they use in Liberia or Myanmar). "dV_h" is ne needed delta V using a Hohmann-Transfer from circular orbits with the same SMA like the real one. So everything now depends on "dV_r": the real delta V has a component for eccentricity and for inclination ... without math I say: In very most cases the inclination part will be much much bigger than the eccentricity!

Comment: @CallMeTom it may depend on exactly how you choose the "ideal Hohmann". Is it for a tangent circular orbit with the same radius as the instantaneous distance to the Sun, or is it for a circular orbit of the same semimajor axis? Mars' eccentricity is about 0.09; it's velocity varies by +/- 2 km/sec and its distance from the Sun by +/- 20 million km! Thus my comment *Maybe it depends on the year?*

Comment: Actually the definition of dV_h  is not as important (just kind of an offset for the MNUs) you just need to keep always the same definition.... most important is the composition of dV_r .... "dV_r = dV_e + dV_i", your qestion is basically: which is bigger dV_i or dV_e .... and I am sure it is for most cases or nearly always dV_i

Comment: If I understand correctly the inclination difference is the reason of _two_ extrema on the porkchop plots for Earth-Mars transfer. Without inclination, with Mars excentricity only, we would have _single_ extremum on porkchop. If I'm right - than the answer is "inclination". But I would hear specialists first...